# How to run Visual Studio CPU profiler on CMake project?

Tags: c++, cmake, profiling, visual-studio-2022

I'm trying to use Visual Studio 2022 and its profiling tools to profile my C++ app, built with a CMake project.

I build my project in RelWithDebInfo mode, and MSVC_x64_x64 toolset.

I added this fragment:

```
if (MSVC)
set_target_properties(${BUILD_TARGET} PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "/PROFILE")
endif()
```

to my CMake file, and with this addition I can choose "Debug->Performance Profiler->Target:{my exe}+CPU usage->Run".

However, after I finish capturing profiling data, I get information, that my program spent 100% of time in function "Idle":

```
 + Idle (PID: 0)    4767 (100,00%)  3335 (69,96%)   Idle
 - [System call]
        ntoskrnl.dll!0xfffff806317fad1e 926 (19,43%)    926 (19,43%)    ntoskrnl
```

And no info about my code whatsoever. What am I doing wrong?

Or is it not possible to debug CMake projects using Visual Studio?

@EDIT

It seems to be a bug in VS2022. I downloaded VS2019 and it's working just fine.

@EDIT

It was already reported a few times, and seems to be related to some bug in Windows 10 kernel. Solutions got already implemented and will be available in the next update.

Comment: Could your write up your findings as an answer and mark it as accepted?

Comment: Is [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/No-Data-in-CPU-Usage-Tool-Windows-Kerne/1573253#TPIN-N1641690) the discussion you are referring to?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will be of use to some lost soul.

I was debugging project with remote VS tools and ran into similar issue. Likely not the same problem, but there was no info about my code and "Idle (PID: 0)" was present. Turns out I had to run cmd as an admin. Server was hardened to a point where tool would run and do something, but it would not do everything it should.