# Visual Studio CPU Performance Profiler for CMake Projects

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, visual-studio-2019

This is NOT a duplicate of [How to run Visual Studio CPU profiler on CMake project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69932843/how-to-run-visual-studio-cpu-profiler-on-cmake-project), since in their case, their program spends 100% of the time in `IDLE`, while mine gives me `[External code]`. They also resolved their problem by running Visual Studio 2019 instead of 2022, while I am using Visual Studio 2019.

I'm trying to profile a CMake project with the Visual Studio Performance Profiler. My project is build with `msvc_x64_x64` in `RelWithDebugInfo`, and I followed [MSVC docs to add the `/profile` flag to CMake](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/profile-performance-tools-profiler?view=msvc-170).

After running the CPU performance profiler, I get everything is running in `[External Code]`, which is completely useless. I wonder if somehow the profiler cannot see the symbols of my project - but I compiled with `RelWithDebugInfo`, so it should be able to. When I ran the profiler, I also selected "Startup Project" rather than a hard-coded path to a binary.

[image]

This is my `CMakeSettings.json` if that's helpful.

```json
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "x64-Debug",
      "generator": "Ninja",
      "configurationType": "Debug",
      "inheritEnvironments": [ "msvc_x64_x64" ],
      "buildRoot": "${projectDir}\\build\\${name}",
      "installRoot": "${projectDir}\\out\\install\\${name}",
      "cmakeCommandArgs": "",
      "buildCommandArgs": "",
      "ctestCommandArgs": ""
    },
    {
      "name": "x64-Release",
      "generator": "Ninja",
      "configurationType": "RelWithDebInfo",
      "buildRoot": "${projectDir}\\build\\${name}",
      "installRoot": "${projectDir}\\out\\install\\${name}",
      "cmakeCommandArgs": "",
      "ctestCommandArgs": "",
      "inheritEnvironments": [ "msvc_x64_x64" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

`ninja -v` verbose output (with include flags removed for brevity):

```
[1/3] C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~2\2019\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1429~1.301\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe  /nologo /TP -DLIBJPEG_STATIC -DLZMA_API_STATIC -DOPJ_STATIC ...[include flags]... /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /GR /EHsc  /MD /Zi /O2 /Ob1 /DNDEBUG -std:c++17 /showIncludes /Fooct-invivo-align\CMakeFiles\oct-invivo-align-test.dir\oct-invivo-align.cpp.obj /Fdoct-invivo-align\CMakeFiles\oct-invivo-align-test.dir\ /FS -c ..\..\oct-invivo-align\oct-invivo-align.cpp
[2/3] C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~2\2019\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1429~1.301\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe  /nologo /TP -DLIBJPEG_STATIC -DLZMA_API_STATIC -DOPJ_STATIC ...[include flags]... /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /GR /EHsc  /MD /Zi /O2 /Ob1 /DNDEBUG -std:c++17 /showIncludes /Fooct-invivo-align\CMakeFiles\oct-invivo-align-test.dir\main.cpp.obj /Fdoct-invivo-align\CMakeFiles\oct-invivo-align-test.dir\ /FS -c ..\..\oct-invivo-align\main.cpp
[3/3] cmd.exe /C "cd . && "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E vs_link_exe --intdir=oct-invivo-align\CMakeFiles\oct-invivo-align-test.dir --rc=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100190~1.0\x64\rc.exe --mt=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100190~1.0\x64\mt.exe --manifests  -- C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~2\2019\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1429~1.301\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe /nologo @CMakeFiles\oct-invivo-align-test.rsp  /out:oct-invivo-align\oct-invivo-align-test.exe /implib:oct-invivo-align\oct-invivo-align-test.lib /pdb:oct-invivo-align\oct-invivo-align-test.pdb /version:0.0 /machine:x64 /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console  && cd ."
```

Comment: Does your debug build show you useful information in the profiler?

Comment: My guess is most likely that your release build is not generating a PDB file.

Comment: @jpr42 The debug build doesn't show useful information in the profiler either. I just checked - there is a PDB file in the release build directory (if my binary is "name.exe", there is a file named "name.pdb" next to it). When I use the debugger, I am able to step through the code, so do you think the debugger is loading the PDB file, but the profiler is not loading the PDB file?

Comment: My thought was you weren't getting useful information due to not having symbol information from the PDB. If you do have a PDB then I'm not sure what's happening.

Comment: Can you provide the verbose output from Ninja? It should look something like this: `[1/3] /usr/bin/g++ -DDEBUG ... -Werror -pedantic -Wall -Wextra ... /home/user/foobar/main.cpp` It may be an issue with your compiler flags.

Comment: Note the example I provided is with `g++` your code will be using `msvc` and have different compiler options

Comment: @jpr42 I added the verbose ninja output to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out all I had to do was to check the `Show External Code` box in `Filter`...

[image]

Comment: Good to hear the answer was simple :)

Comment: @jpr42 i really appreciate your help in the process thanks!